# python plot isn't turning out correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have this code and the expected output is (see first picture) but the actually output is (see 2nd picture).
What is going wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(-.75, 2.25, .001)

p = 1 / (np.cos(t) + np.sin(t))

plt.plot(p)

plt.axis((-1, 2.5, 0, 4))
plt.show()
```

[image: Correct output]

[image: Wrong output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
plt.plot(t, p)
```

What you were doing was plotting `p` against `range(len(p))`, essentially.

Comment: thanks.  Sometimes I don't have to that for that plot.  Could you explain why that is if you know.

Comment: @dustin - If you don't specify a "x" array, matplotlib assumes that you want the array you passed in plotted vs. its indicies (e.g. `range(len(p))`, as Bhajun said).  If you want to plot x vs y, you need to specify x and y, otherwise matplotlib has no way of knowing how the numbers in y were generated or what they relate to.